# How to get rid of gap at top of background image when adapting iphone app to ipad?

Tags: swift, ipad, uiimage

I have recently created an app for iphone 8 plus and am adapting it for ipad. In one of the views I have a background image which is set on an UIImage. In the simulator it displays fine on the iphone 8 plus but in the ipad pro 9.7inch mode there is a white gap at the top. How do I get rid of this gap? I have already tried to make a custom image for that page for the ipad pro version (i.e. making an image size of 768 X 1024) but the gap is still there.

[image: ipad image with gap at top]

The image is set in the imageView in a cell item which in turn is in a collectionView. The cell is set to fill the whole screen with the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: 
UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

The constraints for the imageView have been set to the view with 0:

```
image.top = top
bottom = image.bottom
image.leading = leading
trailing = image.trailing
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this gap?

Comment: Check if this is a part of the `image` itself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've already checked that.